# PHP : Need Help in sorting multidimensional object array ( Array need to sort by [Zone] => stdClass Object ( [Description] => Price B Box Circle)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 66724
        [Zone] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 4156
                [Description] => Price B Box Circle
                [ShortDescription] => B Box     
                [ZoneGroup] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Id] => -1
                    )
            )
        [AvailableCount] => 18
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 66725
        [Zone] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 4157
                [Description] => Price 2 Orchestra Terr Bx Left
                [ShortDescription] => BOrchTrBxL
                [ZoneGroup] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Id] => -1
                        [Description] => (none)
                        [Inactive] => 
                        [Rank] => 0
                    )
            )
        [AvailableCount] => 0
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 66726
        [Zone] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 4158
                [Description] => Price 1 Orchestra
                [ShortDescription] => 1 Orch    
                [ZoneGroup] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Id] => -1
                    )
            )

        [AvailableCount] => 54
    )
[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 66727
        [Zone] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 4159
                [Description] => Price B Orchestra Terr Center
                [ShortDescription] => 1 OrchTr  
                [ZoneGroup] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Id] => -1
                    )
            )
        [ConstituentAvailableCount] => 40
    )
```

Comment: I want to sorry array by  [Zone] => stdClass Object ( [Description] => Price B Box Circle) and result should be 
[Description] => Price B Box Circle
[Description] => Price B Orchestra Terr Centers
[Description] => Price 1 Orchestra

please need urgent help.Many Thanks

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? This looks like a fairly simple usort. Do you know how to reference object properties?

Comment: Use `usort` and compare `$a->Zone->Description` with `$b->Zone->Description`